# Group rows together for filter

Tags: excel, vba, filter, grouping, rows

I have searched all around but no solution had worked so far. 
I have this excel file with random data. Data is seperated by black boarders but there can be any number of cells inbetween. Best if you look at the included file. 
I would like to filter this data, but have no idea, how to group together the rows between the black boarders .... is there any way to do this ?

And my file : 
http://we.tl/UhDJxsqaL1

edit:
If i try to filter by column "A" with value of "18xxxxxx"
then i get what is on the upper side of the image, i would like to get all the values that are on the bottom of the image :

http://s28.postimg.org/6x09tb9t9/koncano.png

Comment: It would be nice to have a screenshot of the expected result or to have a better description

Comment: Is your link for the file working?

Comment: i have edited with additional explanation and an image of what i would like to achieve, yes both links are working.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to copy and past the value of the column A delimited by the border.
Then you will easily be able to filter as you wish.

This is the code:

```
Sub test()


Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To Lastrow

        If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i)) Then

            Copy_Cell_To_Border i

        End If


Next i

End Sub
```

And the sub routine:

```
   Sub Copy_Cell_To_Border(ByVal i As Integer)

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim r As Long

Set cell = Range("A" & i)


    r = 0

    Do
        r = r + 1
    Loop While cell.Offset(r, 0).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone

    If r > 1 Then
        cell.Copy
        Range(cell.Offset(1, 0), cell.Offset(r - 1, 0)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

         If IsEmpty(Range("A" & i - 1)) Then
            Range(cell.Offset(-1, 0), cell.Offset(r - 1, 0)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    End If


End Sub
```

Final result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your attampt, but i already consideret that, the problem with your solution is that its not only first column i need to filter but every collumn, and there can be more than one value in collumn a , sometimes its 18xxxxx and another time 18xxxxx (newline) 15xxxxx which makes this approach not work at all, i even tried making spaces above boarders and then grouping together every row but that doesnt work either